# Unable to click a link for certain column

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click the "RESTORE" hyperlink for a certain version but not working. How can I make it work? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The last column elements:

```
<tbody class="p-datatable-tbody">
    <tr class="p-datatable-row" style="height: 28px;">
        <td class="tbl-row">
            <span style="color: rgba(27, 130, 215, 0.6);">
                <a href="/specification-management/versions/archived?org=Einstein&amp;specName=Edit Specification name&amp;version=2.3&amp;documentSpecId=5dd5d19d554027001896f78b">2.3</a>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="tbl-row">2019-11-20T23:52:18.027Z</td>
        <td class="tbl-row">admin</td>
        <td class="tbl-row"></td>
        <td class="tbl-row">
            <span style="color: rgb(27, 130, 215); text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">RESTORE</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Locators:

```
 DATA_TABLE = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tbody[class="p-datatable-tbody"]')
 DATA_TABLE_ROWS = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr')
 DATA_TABLE_COLUMNS = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td')
```

Method:

```
 def click_restore_link(self, version):
     history_table = self.driver.find_element(*CommonLocators.DATA_TABLE)
     history_table_row = history_table.find_elements(*CommonLocators.DATA_TABLE_ROWS)
     for row in history_table_row:
         table_columns = row.find_elements(*CommonLocators.DATA_TABLE_COLUMNS)
         spec_version = table_columns[0]
         spec_action = table_columns[4]
         if version in spec_version.text:
            spec_action.click()
```

Code: version_history.click_restore_link('2.3')
[History Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjYV8.png)

Comment: Can you post the actual location being given for `CommonLocators.DATA_TABLE_COLUMNS` ? My initial guess is that it's probably returning the `td` element not the `span`

Comment: You are right, the locator is set to td. I tried with span & td span and get "list index out of range" error.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the HTML of the table... at least a representative row. You haven't shared any of your locators... everything is a variable and none of them are defined in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XPath you can create a locator that finds an element based on contained text. For example, we can find the TR that contains version 2.3 and then find the RESTORE link in that row.

Given the HTML you posted, you can write the locator for 2.3 as

```
//table//tr[.//a[.='2.3']]//span[.='RESTORE']
^ start with the table
       ^ that contains a TR
           ^ and that TR contains an A with the text '2.3'
                          ^ and from that TR find the SPAN that contains the text 'RESTORE'
```

With this information, your method would become

```
def click_restore_link(self, version):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table//tr[.//a[.='" + version + "']]//span[.='RESTORE']").click()
```